# Store div background color with a mouse click and release it onto another div when you click it

Tags: javascript

I/'ve been struggling with this problem for a couple of days and tried few different scenarios but no luck.

The goal is to select/store the background color from either of the 2 small colored left cubes (please see fiddle) and release it after clicking on any of the boxes on the right (2x2 - canvas basically)

I tried 3 similar but slightly different JS codes so i will post all 3 of them, if that is against the rules i'll edit to just 1.

For the html and css please open the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/Husky931/cvhoz2af/

Answer assistance in pure JS, no libraries thanks.

TRY 1

```
function setColor() {
    var x = document.getElementById('red').style.backgroundColor;
    localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', x);
  }
  function getColor() {
    var y = document.getElementById('r1b1').style.backgroundColor;
    localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');
  }
```

TRY 2

```
var pickRed = document.getElementById('red');

pickRed.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var redOn = pickRed.style.backgroundColor;
  localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', redOn);

  var releaseRed = document.getElementById('r1b1');
  releaseRed.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var inside = releaseRed.style.backgroundColor;
    inside = localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');    
  });
})
```

TRY 3

```
var selectRed = document.getElementById('red');

selectRed.addEventListener("click", function deployColor() {
  var storeRed = selectRed.style.backgroundColor;
  localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', selectRed);

  var selectR1B1 = document.getElementById('r1b1');
  selectR1B1.addEventListener("click", function() {
     if (!localStorage.getItem('bgcolor')) { // if (!selectR1B1.style.background =='red') 
      selectR1B1.style.backgroundColor = storeRed; //   selectR1B1.style.backgroundColor == 'red';
    }
    else {
      deployColor();
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

```html
<div id="field">

      <div id="leftPalette">
         <div class="paintingCubes" id="red" onclick="localStorage.bgcolor = 'red'"></div>
         <div class="paintingCubes" id="blue" onclick="localStorage.bgcolor = 'blue'"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="canvas">
         <div id="row1">
            <div id="r1d1" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.bgcolor"></div>
            <div id="r1d2" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.bgcolor"></div>            
         </div>
         <div id="row2">
            <div id="r2d1" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.bgcolor"></div>
            <div id="r2d2" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.bgcolor"></div>    
         </div>
      </div>

      <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0hofvL4j/2/

This is the most straightforward you can get for what you want, but not the cleanest as you can see.

You should then cleanup by putting the javascript in your javascript file.

Comment: Great. This is working and seems so simple. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here with JQuery and without localstorage

```
<div id="field">

      <div id="leftPalette">
         <div class="paintingCubes" id="red"></div>
         <div class="paintingCubes" id="blue"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="canvas">
         <div id="row1">
            <div id="r1d1" class="big-rect"></div>
            <div id="r1d2" class="big-rect"></div>            
         </div>
         <div id="row2">
            <div id="r2d1" class="big-rect"></div>
            <div id="r2d2" class="big-rect"></div>    
         </div>
      </div>

      <div id="clear"></div>
</div>     


$(".paintingCubes").on('click', function(){
    $(".paintingCubes").removeClass("selected"); // clearing previous selection
    $(this).addClass("selected");// adding selection to clicked cube
});

$(".big-rect").on("click", function(){
    var color = $(".paintingCubes.selected").css("background-color");
  $(this).css("background-color", color);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but i asked if the answer could be just JS.

Answer (score 0):

This also allows you to add more 'paintingCubes' and 'canvasCubes' without needing to change the javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>        
</head>
<body>      
    <div id="field">

      <div id="leftPalette">
         <div class="paintingCubes" id="red"></div>
         <div class="paintingCubes" id="blue"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="canvas">
         <div id="row1">
            <div id="r1d1" class="canvasCubes"></div>
            <div id="r1d2"  class="canvasCubes"></div>            
         </div>
         <div id="row2">
            <div id="r2d1" class="canvasCubes"></div>
            <div id="r2d2" class="canvasCubes"></div>    
         </div>
      </div>

      <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>           

    </body>

</html>
```

```js
var selectedColor = 'Purple';


function canvasCubeOnClick(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
}

function paintingCubesOnClick(){
    style = getComputedStyle(this);
    sessionStorage.setItem('bgcolor', style.backgroundColor);
  selectedColor = style.backgroundColor;
}

function init(){
    paintingCubes = document.getElementsByClassName('paintingCubes');
    canvasCubes = document.getElementsByClassName('canvasCubes');

  for (var i=0; i<canvasCubes.length; i++){
    canvasCubes[i].addEventListener('click', canvasCubeOnClick);
  }

  for (var i=0; i<paintingCubes.length; i++){
    paintingCubes[i].addEventListener('click', paintingCubesOnClick);
  }  
}

init()
```

Comment: @Husky931 what browser are you using? I tested it on chrome, with jsfiddle, and it worked.